# How am I supposed to write superscript text?

Tags: html, superscript

I have an app which contains plenty of figures or letters in superscript. I noticed that

```
 X<span style="vertical-align: super;">3</span>
```

and just using `sup` tag around the figure 3 both yield `X3` in my app.

But only the `sup` tag yields `X3` on SO. Does it mean I should stick with the latter? What are the differences, pros and cons, if any?

Edit: I have checked http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_sup.asp and http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/sup.html . I don't seem to see any differences.

Comment: Only one adds semantic meaning. Both can be styled in any way desired. If a span 'must' be used, consider using a class and style sheet.

Comment: _'But only the sup tag yields X3 on SO. Does it mean I should stick with the latter?'_ SO filters what code you can use, and it has no bearing on what you should use in your own projects.

Comment: Stephen, you may notice that StackOverflow strips out any `<` and `>` tags from any submitted data, if it is not within a code block or a code line. I *think* you can use superscript style definitions if you use the formatting help on the question and answer textblock areas.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use `<sup>super</sup>`,

As you have seen in the reference from W3C the sup tag is just a routine for the CSS:

```
sup {
    vertical-align: super;
    font-size: smaller;
}
```

Pros: It works across all platforms and this is what it's intended for. Also provides semantic meaning to screen readers and other 'bots.

Cons: Some people just love to do it themselves in CSS.

Edit: And full credit to j08691 - for this very succinct comment:

> SO filters what code you can use, and it has no bearing on what you should use in your own projects

Comment: As a side note, how come you could put <sup></sup> tag in your post and I could not?

Comment: read up on inline code on http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting -- use the backtick character (typically left side of the number 1 on the keyboard top left corner) to encase markup intended to be displayed as code.

Comment: Oh mine, so many little things to learn in here. Thanks @Martin.

Comment: Personally, @StephenAdelakun I found it useful when I saw a post and was "how did they do that"? is to "edit" to view the core of the post and just view the way they got the output they wanted, and then ***cancel the edit***.

Comment: that's smart of you. But you did that because you can edit, isn't it?

Comment: can't you edit other posts? I forget all the ranking and privileges of the SO game system